# How to disable automatic driver installation on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Every time I uninstall a driver and restart the computer, Windows 7 reinstalls the driver when the computer starts back up. I have already told Windows 7 to "never install driver software from Windows Update" under Device Installation settings. I also don't have access to the Group Policy Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't actually ask a question (you just explained a situation), I assume the answer is to disable the device in Device Manager.

Comment: The question is in the title, so I didn't feel the need to type it again. I want to permanently remove the driver rather than disable it to prevent possible conflicts or bugs and the way Windows 7 handles device detection will not let me do so.

Comment: What is the device. Disabling the device should stop it being used and therefore some what irrelevant as to if the driver is installed or not for the actual device.

Comment: trying to remove IDT High Definition Audio CODEC

Comment: OK - when I tried to remove my audio device for my music PC (where I have an external sound card), I disabled the on-board audio from the BIOS. Not sure if this helps. Can you confirm if you have a 'replacement' audio device

Comment: I have a Creative X-fi USB sound card